# Passing data between windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Assuming I have a window that looks something like this:

```xml
<Window>

    <Window.Resources>
    
        <ResourceDictionary>
        
            <controllers:MainWindowController x:Key="Controller" />
        
        </ResourceDictionary>
    
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Window.DataContext>
    
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Controller}" />
    
    </Window.DataContext>
    
    <Grid Margin="5">
    
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
            <RowDefinition />
            
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
                 Margin="0, 0, 0, 2.5"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                 
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0, 2.5, 0, 0"
                Command="{Binding DisplayUserInfoCommand}" />
    
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

and the `MainWindowController` class is something like:

```cs
public sealed class MainWindowController : ReactiveObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    
    public User SelectedUser { get; set; }
    
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> DisplaySelectedUserInfoCommand { get; }
    
    public MainWindowController()
    {
        DisplaySelectedUserInfoCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(DisplaySelectedUserInfoCommandHandler);
    }
    
    private void DisplaySelectedUserInfoCommandHandler()
    {
        if (SelectedUser == null) return;
        
        // TODO: pass SelectedUser to the newly created UserInfoWindow.
        _ = new UserInfoWindow().ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

the `User` is a record that looks like this:

```cs
public sealed record User(string Name, string Email, string Phone);
```

and the `UserInfoWindow` is something like:

```xml
<Window>

    <Window.Resources>
    
        <ResourceDictionary>
        
            <controllers:UserInfoWindowController x:Key="Controller" />
        
        </ResourceDictionary>
    
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Window.DataContext>
    
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Controller}" />
    
    </Window.DataContext>
    
    <Grid Margin="5">
    
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
            <RowDefinition />
            
            <RowDefinition />
        
            <RowDefinition />
        
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Margin="0, 0, 0, 2.5"
               Content="{Binding User.Name}" 
               ContentStringFormat="Name: {0}" />
               
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Margin="0, 2.5, 0, 2.5"
               Content="{Binding User.Email}" 
               ContentStringFormat="Email: {0}" />
               
        <Label Grid.Row="2"
               Margin="0, 2.5, 0, 0"
               Content="{Binding User.Phone}" 
               ContentStringFormat="Phone: {0}" />
    
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

and the `UserInfoWindowController` is something like this:

```cs
public sealed class UserInfoWindowController : ReactiveObject
{
    private User _user;
    
    public User User
    {
        get => _user;
        
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _user, value);
    }
}
```

how can I pass the `SelectedUser` from the `MainWindowController` to the newly created `UserInfoWindow` without manually passing a new instance of `UserInfoWindowController` to it upon its creation or setting the `DataContext` via code?

***Notes:***

- The XAML code above isn't "complete" since I have stripped some unnecessary attributes for the sake of keeping the post short.
- I've omitted the `using` directives from the C# code for the same reason as above.
- I'm using ReactiveUI.
- My WPF application is using .NET 5.

Comment: UserInfoWindow ViewModel is irrelevant with a selected user isn't it? So its constructor should ask for a UserInfo object.

Comment: The essential details of your implementation are missing to answer your question.
First of all, these are: How do you create and display the second Window?
This moment is important, since the transfer of data to it should be carried out exactly at this moment.

Comment: The second important point.
Since the user's selection happens in the MainWindowController, why didn't you declare a property of type UserInfoWindowController for the selected user here?
Then the second Window could receive this controller into its DataContext.

Comment: Third point.
As I understand it, you do not provide for several main Windows.
And the created instance of MainWindowController must exist for the entire duration of the application session.
Why then do you declare the MainWindowController instance in the Window resources and not in the App Resources?

Comment: "The essential details of your implementation are missing to answer your question. First of all, these are: How do you create and display the second Window? This moment is important since the transfer of data to it should be carried out exactly at this moment." - @EldHasp what "essential" details are missing? I've clearly shown that I create and show the second window by using `_ = new UserInfoWindow().ShowDialog()` in the examples above.

Comment: "The second important point. Since the user's selection happens in the MainWindowController, why didn't you declare a property of type UserInfoWindowController for the selected user here? Then the second Window could receive this controller into its DataContext." - @EldHasp a controller is not supposed to contain or know about other controllers it's supposed to encapsulate functionality related to a single window that's why.

Comment: "Third point. As I understand it, you do not provide for several main Windows. And the created instance of MainWindowController must exist for the entire duration of the application session. Why then do you declare the MainWindowController instance in the Window resources and not in the App Resources?" - @EldHasp again, the controllers encpsulate functionality required by a single window and must not be shared between different windows or know about other controllers/windows.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your code correctly and additional explanations in the comments, then I think this solution should work:

```
    private void DisplaySelectedUserInfoCommandHandler()
    {
        if (SelectedUser == null) return;
        
        // TODO: pass SelectedUser to the newly created UserInfoWindow.
        var win = new UserInfoWindow();

        var contr = (UserInfoWindowController) win.Resources["Controller"];
        contr.User = SelectedUser;

        win.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**Another possible option:**

```
   public UserInfoWindowController(User user)
     : this()
   {
        var contr = (UserInfoWindowController) Resources["Controller"];
        contr.User = user;
   }
```

```
    private void DisplaySelectedUserInfoCommandHandler()
    {
        if (SelectedUser == null) return;
        
        // TODO: pass SelectedUser to the newly created UserInfoWindow.
        _ = new UserInfoWindow(SelectedUser).ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: I was already using something similar to the second solution but instead of using `(UserInfoWindowController)Resources["Controller"]` I was doing `((UserInfoWindowController)DataContext).User = user`

Comment: If there is nothing else in the `UserInfoWindowController` class besides the User property, then yes - you can do that.